# Eclipse RCP, how to highlight occurrences (or write) of selection dynamically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

As my question, I'd like to know, what need to be done to implement occurrences (or write) highlight dynamically, which like java editor does.

Current, there is good syntax highlight and basic code partitions (multiple line comment, single line comment, others). What do i need to do next for implementing the dynamical highlight?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So have you used an `IDocumentPartitioner` to split up the document?

Comment: Yes, i have one already, i separate document into 3 content types, multiple line comment, single line comment and IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE. Each one connects to one pair of damager and repairer.